# US citizen travelling to Dubai, can I get a visa on arrival?

Tags: visas, us-citizens, dubai

I am a US citizen traveling to India in Jan 2016 to meet relatives and friends.
From India I am planing to go to Dubai for a couple of days via private tour. 
Do I need to get Dubai visa in advance ? Or I will get visa on arrival?

Comment: You said Indian in title, but US citizen in body, do you mean you have dual nationality? As long as you show/use your US passport to UAE Authorities, airlines involved, you will get visa on arrival. If you show Indian Passport to airline while checking in for UAE flight, you will be denied boarding as Indians need a Visa before boarding.

Comment: @Davinder looking at the revision history I think the "Indian citizen" was erroneously introduced into the title by JoErNanO, I'll ping him.

Answer (score 5):

Yes you need a visa but they can be obtained online or on arrival, free or charge for a maximum stay of 30 days. According to [Timatic](http://www.emirates.com/us/english/plan_book/essential_information/visa_passport_information/find_visa_requirements/visa_passport_information_results.aspx?NC=US&NV=United+States&DC=AE&DV=United+Arab+Emirates&h=5c21112b31a869e1b65be9775c736cc1128b4949)

[image]